# What is the benefit of using create2() to create a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, assembly, factory, create2

Why would someone use [create2()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/assembly.html#opcodes) inline assembly code to create a child contract in factory pattern as opposed to using `newContract()` to create an instance of "newContract"?

What are the upsides and downsides of using one over the other?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**CREATE** opcode is used by default when deploying smart contracts. The deployed contract address is calculated like this.

```
keccak256(senderAddress, nonce)
```

**CREATE2** opcode is introduced later and allows you to **predetermine the contract address**. Contract address is computed like this.

```
keccak256(0xFF, senderAddress, salt, bytecode)
```

`0xFF` parameter is a constant to prevent collision with CREATE opcode.

`salt` parameter is a value sender sends when deploying contract.

`bytecode` parameter is, you probably guessed it, the bytecode of the smart contract you want to deploy.

If you want to predetermine the contract address before deploying, you can simply loop through different `salt` values and select the one you like (or want).

A great example of using CREATE2 can be seen here. [Application of `CREATE2` opcode](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/a43tzv/example_of_how_to_use_the_new_create2_opcode_in/ebdeu00)

**Edit**: Creating a contract with `new` keyword requires you to know the contract's source code. After creating a contract with `new` keyword, it will return the created contract's address.

This also uses `CREATE` opcode behind to create the contract.

Comment: What about just calling the smart `contract()` ? Also what are the applications of knowing a contract address before you create it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an example you can refer this link, using CREATE2 one project can deploy with same contract address on multiple chains.

https://github.com/Elefria-Labs/playground-contracts/blob/main/test/Create2.test.ts