# what does keyword "salt" mean in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

"Contracts can be created by other contracts using the new keyword. Since 0.8.0, new keyword supports create2 feature by specifying salt options."

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract Car {
address public owner;
string public model;
address public carAddr;

constructor(address _owner, string memory _model) payable {
    owner = _owner;
    model = _model;
    carAddr = address(this);
  }
}

contract CarFactory {
Car[] public cars;

function create(address _owner, string memory _model) public {
    Car car = new Car(_owner, _model);
    cars.push(car);
}

function createAndSendEther(address _owner, string memory _model) public payable {
    Car car = (new Car){value: msg.value}(_owner, _model);
    cars.push(car);
}

function create2(
    address _owner,
    string memory _model,
    bytes32 _salt
) public {
    Car car = (new Car){salt: _salt}(_owner, _model);
    cars.push(car);
}

function create2AndSendEther(
    address _owner,
    string memory _model,
    bytes32 _salt
) public payable {
    Car car = (new Car){value: msg.value, salt: _salt}(_owner, _model);
    cars.push(car);
}

function getCar(uint _index)
    public
    view
    returns (
        address owner,
        string memory model,
        address carAddr,
        uint balance
    )
{
    Car car = cars[_index];

    return (car.owner(), car.model(), car.carAddr(), address(car).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A salt (in cryptography) is a bit of randomness added to a transaction (usually inputs to a hashing function) in order to make discovering a secret (key) harder.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Answer (score 5):

**According to the [Solidity docs:](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#salted-contract-creations-create2)**

> "When creating a contract, the address of the contract is computed from the address of the creating contract and a counter that is
> increased with each contract creation.
>
> If you specify the option salt (a bytes32 value), then contract creation will use a different mechanism to come up with the address of
> the new contract: It will compute the address from the address of the
> creating contract, the given salt value, the (creation) bytecode of
> the created contract and the constructor arguments."

This allows you to predict the contract address before it is created, [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#salted-contract-creations-create2) is the example code that solidity provides:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    contract D {
        uint public x;
        constructor(uint a) {
            x = a;
        }
    }
    
    contract C {
        function createDSalted(bytes32 salt, uint arg) public {
            // This complicated expression just tells you how the address
            // can be pre-computed. It is just there for illustration.
            // You actually only need ``new D{salt: salt}(arg)``.
            address predictedAddress = address(uint160(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                bytes1(0xff),
                address(this),
                salt,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                    type(D).creationCode,
                    abi.encode(arg)
                ))
            )))));
    
            D d = new D{salt: salt}(arg);
            require(address(d) == predictedAddress);
        }
    }
```

I encourage you to go to the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#salted-contract-creations-create2) to read more about it including the main use case and a peculiar warning about using salt.

Answer (score 1):

salt parameter is a value sender sends when deploying contract

Taken from: [What is the benefit of using create2() to create a smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101336/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-create2-to-create-a-smart-contract)